# How do I know whether I'm using CommonJS, AMD, or neither?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, amd, commonjs

I'm currently trying to include

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

But when I load it I get:

```
VM1613:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

`d3` should be a global object. On their website though they state:

> The default UMD bundle is now anonymous. No `d3` global is exported if AMD or CommonJS is detected. In a vanilla environment, the D3 microlibraries share the `d3` global, even if you load them independently; thus, code you write is the same whether or not you use the default bundle.

I have no idea what AMD or CommonJS is but this may be used in our environment. Is there any way to quickly check whether CommonJS or AMD is causing my issue with the `d3` object?

Comment: in which browser are you getting this?

Comment: Are you loading the D3 library before your own script?